# Jquery datatable pass string array as parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I want to send string array as a parameter to the server side. But this doesn't work. But I can send a string as a paramter to the server side without any issue. These data send to the mvc controller. I am using jquery datatable 1.10.16.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "test/getall",
            "data": function ( d ) {
                d.Ids = ["123", "333", "444"]; 
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: I don't know about jquery datatable, but maybe you can use array.join() to convert it to a string?

Comment: Use `'contentType': "application/json"` and `return JSON.stringify(d.Ids)` to serialize array into JSON format. Make sure the controller action method has string array as argument.

Comment: @Ray : yes, that's possible. As a string, I can submit to the serverside and then do the breakdown on the server side. But I want to know the way to pass as a string array to the server side.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, Or just use `traditional: true` (since its an array of simple values)

Comment: What is the signature of the controller method?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : That works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
string strCommaSepList =  "123,333,444";
//convert to string array

string[] strCommanSepArray = strCommaSepList.Split(",");
```

Another way you can choose to send data to server.
If you send data by comma saperated string like "123,333,444"
Then on the server side you can make it an array via built in explode function

Answer (score 0):

As @TetsuyaYamamoto suggested, it can be achieved by adding **"contentType": "application/json"** to the request and return data as a json using **return JSON.stringify(d)**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "test/getall",
                "contentType": "application/json",
                "data": function ( d ) {
                    d.Ids = ["123", "333", "444"]; 

                    return JSON.stringify(d);
                }
            }
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: Both `"contentType": "application/json"` and `return JSON.stringify(d);` is completely unnecessary.  JSON is expected, anything else will fail, `data()` does not expect a return value, the meaning is you work on the `d` literal and stringifying it is meaningless.

Comment: @davidkonrad : Yes without those two, It works as long as you are not passing an array to the server side. The problem arises when you try to pass an array as a parameter.

Comment: Well, I guess it is a serverside problem then?  The backend script is not written to or prepared for accepting arrays? I just tried the example in PHP (does not have ASP) without `contentType` and stringifying,, `$_GET['Ids']` echoes out the string `["123", "333", "444"]` so your backend script just need to parse that into an array? BTW, have you considered that `cache` had some influence on how it suddenly worked?  Anyway, great you got it to work :)

Comment: @davidkonrad, asp.net-mvc is not php. OP does require either `contentType": "application/json"` and `JSON.stringify(d);` or `traditional: true,` in the ajax options for it to work

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes, PHP is not ASP, and ...?? We are clientside here. DataTables already stringify the data params under the hood, and as said it does not even take notice of a return value, the data callback is just a DataTables feature improvement of jQuery AJAX that let you work on the data literal "on the fly", see https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Comment: @davidkonrad, I do not know why you are trying to say (the link has nothing to do with the question). OP is making an ajax call to a controller method. The only way the asp.net-mvc `DefaultModelBinder` will bind the array of values they are sending to their `int[]` parameter in their method is if they use the correct ajax options

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I cannot believe ASP not can handle a `{"Ids":["123","333","444"]}` string.  That is what will be sent also without `"contentType": "application/json"`, which define the **respond** type, not the `dataType`, and without `JSON.stringify()` which **always** will be made before the request is sent anyway.

Comment: @davidkonrad. Because the default in mvc is the same as the default in ajax, which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In order to parse that data, the `contentType` must be specified so that the `DefautModelBinder` uses the `JsonValueProviderFactory` to bind the results (or OP can use `traditional: true` so that its sent as `Ids=123&Ids=333&....`) which means that it does not need to be stringified or have the `contentType` set)

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer array, maybe this code will help you

```
      "ajax": {
                "url": "testUrl",
                "data": function(d) {
                    d.ids=integerArray.join(',');
                 },
              }
```